# Consider adding this directory to PATH

Tags: python, pip, path

I'm trying to set up on Mac Catalina (without using anaconda because it has been troublesome).

I'm getting the following warnings after running `pip3 install --user jupyterlab` I'd like to correct them but I'm not confident in my understanding of PATH and command line stuff.

````
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script jsonschema is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script jupyter-trust is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The scripts jupyter-kernel, jupyter-kernelspec and jupyter-run are installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script pygmentize is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The scripts iptest, iptest3, ipython and ipython3 are installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script jupyter-nbconvert is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The scripts jupyter-bundlerextension, jupyter-nbextension, jupyter-notebook and jupyter-serverextension are installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script chardetect is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The script pyjson5 is installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
     WARNING: The scripts jlpm, jupyter-lab, jupyter-labextension and jupyter-labhub are installed in '/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin' which is not on PATH.
     Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.```


How do I do this?
````

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bosx%5D+add+directory+PATH

Comment: Add this to `~/.bash_profile`: `export PATH="$PATH":/Users/joshuabennett/Library/Python/3.9/bin`